# What is the meaning of "twists and turns" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The car followed the twists and turns of the mountain road.

Comment: It's literal - if you can picture a mountain road, it usually snakes up the mountain with sharp turns and from a distance, looks like a twisting ribbon on the side of the mountain.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I'd vote for that answer

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: I don't think such an obvious response to a General Reference question needs to be posted as an answer and voted on. An informative comment or link is quite sufficient.

Comment: I was under the impression this was a question and _answer_ site, not a question and comment site.

Answer (score 2):

It's literal - if you can picture a mountain road, it usually snakes up the mountain with sharp turns and from a distance, looks like a twisting ribbon on the side of the mountain. (thanks @ElendilTheTall!)

[image: Winding mountain road]

Comment: Could this be rephrased as "full of bends"?

Comment: @user36663 - sure it could and would be very descriptive also.  "Twists and turns", however, is a common expression that feels good to the ear and tongue due to its alliterativeness (both words start with "T").  Say it a few times out loud! :-)

Comment: Something tells me I have to explicitly state that it *can't* be replaced with "full of bends" *in the sentence in question*.